# Python class use shared state for function?

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I am trying to improve my python code and have started using classes to group related methods and variables.

What is the best practice when using a function that is able to access the variables that are initialized in the class? Should I just access the variable in the function? Or explicitly pass the variable to make it clear that I am relying on it?

I've created two examples to show what I mean by this question. Which method is preferred?

```
# method 1
class UploadForm(object):
    def __init__(self, form_data):
        self.file_name = form_data.get('file_name')

    def validate(self):
        agency_name = self.extract_agency_name(self.file_name)

    @staticmethod
    def extract_agency_name(file_name):
        pattern = re.search('^[CFS]Y\d{4} (.+?)[.](?:xls|csv)$', file_name, re.I)
        if pattern:
            agency_name = pattern.group(1)
            return agency_name


# method 2
class UploadForm(object):
    def __init__(self, form_data):
        self.file_name = form_data.get('file_name')

    def validate(self):
        agency_name = self.extract_agency_name()

    def extract_agency_name(self):
        pattern = re.search('^[CFS]Y\d{4} (.+?)[.](?:xls|csv)$', self.file_name, re.I)
        if pattern:
            agency_name = pattern.group(1)
            return agency_name
```

Comment: If you are going to use a class to share state then yes, use instance variables

Comment: Method 2, keep interface as simple as possible.  If `extract_agency_name` isn't really specific to any object, then make it a module function that the class calls like in method 1.

Comment: Thank you to you both. I'll stick with method 2, and will consider moving those functions outside the class.

Comment: Your `pattern` variable would be better named `match`, as it represents the result of the regular expression match, not the pattern used to search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For reasons below method 2 is preferred.

1. A member variable should be accessed via **self**.

   - By using self, you are making clear that you are referencing **file_name** variable of the same object.
2. Decorators can become overheads.

   - Decorators are wrappers around a method or a variable.
3. Passing more argument is more memory consuming.

   - Each argument takes up memory.

Comment: If you're worrying about the overhead of a decorator or the memory associated with passing an argument (which should just be the memory associated with the name binding), you shouldn't be writing the code in Python.

Comment: @jpmc26 Well compared to other languages, you are very correct. I was only considering the two cases above.

Comment: My point is that the performance concerns you bring up are trivial. Changing those facets are *not* techniques you should be using to optimize.